# How to use curl -F in nodejs?

Tags: node.js

I am trying to build a website that connect with Instagram.

And I want to subscribe Instagram's tag for real time.

```
curl -F 'client_id=CLIENT-ID' \
 -F 'client_secret=CLIENT-SECRET' \
 -F 'object=tag' \
 -F 'aspect=media' \
 -F 'object_id=nofilter' \
 -F 'callback_url=http://YOUR-CALLBACK/URL' \
 https://api.instagram.com/v1/subscriptions/
```

I really don't know how to do this in nodejs.

Comment: What do you have so far?

Comment: `require('request')` would be a start

Comment: i think you are really looking for how to make a request, not how to use curl in nodejs, because I don't think you can use curl from within nodejs...

Comment: possible duplicate of [Curl equivalent in nodejs?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6819143/curl-equivalent-in-nodejs)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll need the request library for the following code. https://github.com/request/request

```
var request = require('request');

var formData = {
  client_secret: "CLIENT-SECRET",
  object: "tag",
  aspect: "media",
  "object_id": "nofilter",
  "callback_url": "http://YOUR-CALLBACK/URL"
};

request.post({
  url: "https://api.instagram.com/v1/subscriptions/",
  formData: formData
}, function (err, res, body) {
  if (err) {
    console.log(err);
  } else {
    console.log(body);
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

As others have said, request is likely the easiest solution.  However, if you have to use curl directly, the following can work natively:

```
var spawn = require('child_process').spawn;

var command = spawn('curl', []);

command.stderr.on('data', function(data) { });

command.stdout.on('data', function(data) { });

command.stdout.on('close', function() {  });
```

See [spawn command arguments](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_spawn_command_args_options) for more information.  Alternatively, [node-curl](https://github.com/jiangmiao/node-curl) is available.