# cant install node-libcurl on debian

Tags: node.js, curl, debian

Tell me, please, why I cannot install node-libcurl. Here are the errors displayed when installing (npm install node-libcurl):

```
> node-libcurl@1.3.0 install /var/www/node/node_modules/node-libcurl
> node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build

node-pre-gyp ERR! Tried to download(404): https://github.com/JCMais/node-libcurl/releases/download/v1.3.0/node_libcurl-v1.3.0-node-v57-linux-x64.tar.gz
node-pre-gyp ERR! Pre-built binaries not found for node-libcurl@1.3.0 and node@8.9.4 (node-v57 ABI, glibc) (falling back to source compile with node-gyp)
gyp ERR! build error
gyp ERR! stack Error: not found: make
gyp ERR! stack     at getNotFoundError (/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/which/which.js:13:12)
gyp ERR! stack     at F (/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/which/which.js:68:19)
gyp ERR! stack     at E (/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/which/which.js:80:29)
gyp ERR! stack     at /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/which/which.js:89:16
gyp ERR! stack     at /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/which/node_modules/isexe/index.js:42:5
gyp ERR! stack     at /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/which/node_modules/isexe/mode.js:8:5
gyp ERR! stack     at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:152:21)
gyp ERR! System Linux 2.6.32-042stab127.2
gyp ERR! command "/usr/bin/node" "/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "build" "--fallback-to-build" "--module=/var/www/node/node_modules/node-libcurl/lib/binding/node_libcurl.node" "--module_name=node_libcurl" "--module_path=/var/www/node/node_modules/node-libcurl/lib/binding"
gyp ERR! cwd /var/www/node/node_modules/node-libcurl
gyp ERR! node -v v8.9.4
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.6.2
gyp ERR! not ok
node-pre-gyp ERR! build error
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack Error: Failed to execute '/usr/bin/node /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js build --fallback-to-build --module=/var/www/node/node_modules/node-libcurl/lib/binding/node_libcurl.node --module_name=node_libcurl --module_path=/var/www/node/node_modules/node-libcurl/lib/binding' (1)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/var/www/node/node_modules/node-libcurl/node_modules/node-pre-gyp/lib/util/compile.js:83:29)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at emitTwo (events.js:126:13)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:214:7)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:925:16)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:209:5)
node-pre-gyp ERR! System Linux 2.6.32-042stab127.2
node-pre-gyp ERR! command "/usr/bin/node" "/var/www/node/node_modules/node-libcurl/node_modules/.bin/node-pre-gyp" "install" "--fallback-to-build"
node-pre-gyp ERR! cwd /var/www/node/node_modules/node-libcurl
node-pre-gyp ERR! node -v v8.9.4
node-pre-gyp ERR! node-pre-gyp -v v0.6.39
node-pre-gyp ERR! not ok
Failed to execute '/usr/bin/node /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js build --fallback-to-build --module=/var/www/node/node_modules/node-libcurl/lib/binding/node_libcurl.node --module_name=node_libcurl --module_path=/var/www/node/node_modules/node-libcurl/lib/binding' (1)
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! node-libcurl@1.3.0 install: `node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the node-libcurl@1.3.0 install script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2018-03-04T22_33_32_704Z-debug.log
```

Comment: Don't put links but text in your post

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Install the dependencies:

```
# apt install build-essential libssl-dev libcurl4-gnutls-dev libcurl4-openssl-dev
```

Install the [Node.js V9](https://nodejs.org/en/download/package-manager/) :

```
curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_9.x | sudo -E bash -
sudo apt-get install -y nodejs
```

The installation process should work without problem using the `5.6.0` npm version:

```
$ npm init
$ npm install node-libcurl --save
```

Check:

```
npm ls | grep node-libcurl 
node-libcurl@1.3.0
```

Comment: I use `node 15`, so going down to `node v9` does not make sense to install `node-libcurl`. Regarding `apt install` I get `Die folgenden Pakete haben unerfüllte Abhängigkeiten:
 libcurl4-gnutls-dev : Kollidiert mit: libcurl4-openssl-dev aber 7.68.0-1ubuntu2.6 soll installiert werden`. Maybe your answer needs newer package versions?