# Need help to induction curl Post in code JS / Node.js

Tags: javascript, curl, post

curl -X POST -H 'Content-type: application/json' --data '{"text":"Hello, World!"}'....

It works if I use this in the console.
How can I implement this in JS code?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Curl equivalent in nodejs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6819143/curl-equivalent-in-nodejs)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless there's something I'm missing about curl, you could use fetch to make a similar request:

```js
fetch(urlToPostTo, {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
      'Accept': 'application/json',
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({text: 'Hello, World!'})
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

In your node application use proper package for curl like:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/curl-request

https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-curl

with both you will recreate easily curl request you want.

of course this will require nodeJS application and cannot be used in client-side javascript code.

Comment: OP does not mention he uses Node. He mentions that he used console, which is frontend.

Comment: he used console to run curl. So its mean system console :)

Answer (score 0):

You can implement this in many different ways, either by using one of the libraries such as [Axios](https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios) or [Jquery](https://jquery.com/). Or using Javascript built in ways such as [fetch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API), or even building your own [XMLHttpRequest()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest)

I believe the easiest way for you would be to use Axios. Of course, you can experiment with others as well.

I will not post examples how to make a GET request, since the links I provided have examples already.

Have fun.